# UIBarButtonItem appearance and setBackButtonBackgroundImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I change my back button when pushing a new viewcontroller in my navigationcontroller. But it doesnt look nice and its stretched. Also, how can I remove the "News" title in my back button?
here's my code. see the image

[image: screen shoot]

and the code is

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I want to achieve something like this http://i228.photobucket.com/albums/ee262/romano2717/photo4.png

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm going through the same problem right now...

Answer (score 18):

Use the following code to put the image in position.

```
int imageSize = 20; //REPLACE WITH YOUR IMAGE WIDTH

UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBackButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, imageSize, 0, 0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImg 
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can use resizableImageWithCapInsets to specify which pixels should not be stretched. If you put your image-width in there it won't stretch your image.

You don't have to put it in the .m file btw. (You could use the appDelegate.m file) just make sure it get's called before the NavigationBar is drawn.

Comment: any idea how to remove the title ??

Comment: Sure: [[self navigationItem] setTitle:nil];

Comment: Or do you mean the button's title?

Comment: I'd like to know the trick to remove the buttons title for back button in the whole app ;)

Comment: try [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-99, -99) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: ^ title position adjustment is NOT a good UIAppearance solution... the back button's frame is still set for it's title, resulting in misalignment issues on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you have to create the UIBarButtonItem in code to remove or change the title, so it would only apply to the view controllers you put the code in:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
[myBackButton release];
```

The reason why the code you posted works that way is because it only sets the background and the documentation does state that:

> For good results, backgroundImage must be a stretchable image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Button and add it as a bar button to remove the stretch. or you can get graphics of back button size.

to remove the title of the button you have to set `self.title = "";`  in viewWillDisappear method and set title again when in viewWillAppear method.

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: When I add this code the back button is gone after pushing the new viewcontroller to the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use youparentViewController.title = @" ";
I did have the same problem with the title

Answer (score -3):

Below code will Remove Title from the Back button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *theBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourAction)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackBarButtonItem:theBackButton];    
    [theBackButton release];
```

Comment: This crashes with `-[_UIBarItemAppearance setBackBarButtonItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208448d0` on 6.0.1